# stick it up your a**

Tags: idioms, american-english

Is there a reason why, we use "up" and not "in". I always thought it wasn't intuitive to use "up", is there a semantic reason, or is it "cultural" or "historical"? Can someone explain, so that a non-native English speaker may understand why "up" "makes perfect sense" in this vulgar expression? Also, is there any similar example where we use "up" in a similar manner?

Comment: Is there a reason why it was downvoted? It was a genuine question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent, the idiom is what it is because it is.  These things don't always have to make sense.

However, in this case the general phrase "to stick something *in* somewhere" is different from "to stick something *up* somewhere".

> Just stick that box **in** the back of the garage.
>
> Just stick that probe **up** the access shaft so we can see if there is any blockage.

The first mostly implies simple *location*, while the second implies more *forceful action*, in an *upward* direction.  Given this particular location ("your ass"), using "up" conveys a sense of an *unpleasant* intrusion.

I might be reading too much into it, and it could simply be an expression of direction.  There is a less vulgar variation, *"Stick in in your ear"*, that isn't much used these days.  You wouldn't say "up" your ear, because the direction is more *inward* than *upward*.